# Chat GPT API keys

Tags: model, chatbot, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am sorry if this sounds like a dumb question, but I am trying to built and connect a custom GPT to a WhatsApp account. However, I need an API key for this from OpenAI. Can I use the API key from another ChatGPT 4 account to connect this custom model (which is on a different GPT 4 account) to WhatsApp? Or is that not possible? Can someone please elaborate on this and how OpenAI API keys for ChatGPT work in general? Thank you.

Since the API key requires credit, I was wondering if it would be possible to use one from another ChatGPT account that does have credit.

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid API Key. The key can be created using your subscription with OpenAPI. It doesn't matter who the key belongs to, when you use it, OpenAI will charge the account bound to that key. Just that simple. Until you pay for the quota you can use it. Otherwise you'll get an error from the API to inform you that your quota has been depleted.